# How to avoid Segmentation fault in pycocotools during decoding of RLE

Tags: python, rle, pycocotools

Here is a sample of decoding corrupted RLE:

```
from pycocotools import mask  # pycocotools version is 2.0.2
mask.decode({'size': [1024, 1024], 'counts': "OeSOk0[l0VOaSOn0kh0cNmYO'"})
```

As result it fails with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

It looks like this:

```
Python 3.6.15 (default) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from pycocotools import mask
>>> mask.decode({'size': [1024, 1024], 'counts': "OeSOk0[l0VOaSOn0kh0cNmYO'"})
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Questions**:

1. Is the way to validate RLE(Run-length encoding) before putting it in into mask.decode?
2. (I think it's not possible, but still) Is the way to handle `signal.SIGSEGV` and continue executing of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by updating **pycocotools** to version **2.0.5**